# Convert a list of tuples to dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary, tuples

I have a list of tuples that I would like to convert to a dictionary. Each of the tuples in the list has four elements:

`N = [('WA', 'OR', 'CA', 'HI'), ('MA', 'NY', 'PA', 'FL')]`

How do I get a dictionary set up where the first element of the tuple is the key, and the value is a tuple of the rest of the elements?

`dict = {"WA": ("OR", "CA", "HI"), "MA": ("NY", "PA", "FL")}`

I tried something along the lines of this, but I am getting a truncated version of the fourth element (at least that what it looks like to me, my actual list is much larger than the example list):

```
for i in range(len(N))}:
    for v in N[i]:
        dict[i] = v[1:4]
```

Answer (score 11):

Think about it inside out.  Given a single tuple, how do you make a key value pair?

```
tup[0]: tup[1:]
```

Now just wrap this in the dictionary:

```py
d = {tup[0]: tup[1:] for tup in N}
```

Answer (score 3):

In your code `v[1:4]` is already each element of the tuple. That is why the first character is ignored.

You don't need a nested loop.

You can use a dict comprehension (obviously use better variable names):

```
N = [('WA', 'OR', 'CA', 'HI'), ('MA', 'NY', 'PA', 'FL')]
d = {t[0]: t[1:] for t in N}
print(d)
```

outputs

```
{'WA': ('OR', 'CA', 'HI'), 'MA': ('NY', 'PA', 'FL')}
```

You could also use `dict` directly. It accepts an iterable of tuples where the first element will be the key and the second element will be the value.

```
d = dict((t[0], t[1:]) for t in N)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```py
>>> N = [('WA', 'OR', 'CA', 'HI'), ('MA', 'NY', 'PA', 'FL')]
>> d = {key: (*values,) for key, *values in N}
>>> d
{'WA': ('OR', 'CA', 'HI'), 'MA': ('NY', 'PA', 'FL')}
```

`for key, *values in N` means that it will take the first element of each tuple as `key`, and it will put the remaining elements in `values`.

Comment: Or `{key: (*values,) for key, *values in N}` but yours is explicit, so that's better.

Comment: This seems to be doing tons of extra unnecessary work (unpacking and repacking the tuple)

Comment: @DeepSpace, the user is not stating "without doing extra unnecessary work", he is just asking for a solution. I focused on readability, but thanks for mentioning in case that matters more for him.